# Remote validator with DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

I'm trying (without success) to use the Remote validator on a DropDownList:

```
// Person.cs
public int PersonID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

// Card.cs
public int CardID { get; set; }
[Remote("PersonValidation", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "...")]
public int PersonID { get; set; }
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

// CardController
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.PersonID = new SelectList(db.Persons, "PersonID", "Name");
    Card card = new Card();
    return View(card);
} 

// create.cshtml (Card Views)
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.personID, "Person")</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("PersonID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonID)
</div>

// ValidationController.cs
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public JsonResult PersonValidation(int id)
{
    Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    return Json(person.Cards.Count > 0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The PersonValidation is never fired. The others "Remote" validations with text input are working perfectly.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with DropDownList Remote validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The validator does not fire because you need to use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` in order to create an HTML element with "data-val" elements, which will be parsed into unobtrusive validators.

Comment: Sorry counsellorben, I try @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonID, null, "") but there has still no client validation for this field. Can you give me a hand please?

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML, does the <select> element contain `data-val="true"`?  If not, there are issues with DropDownListFor not emitting unobtrusive validation attributes.  See http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7629

Comment: <div class="editor-field">
  <select id="PersonID" name="PersonID"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">AAA</option>
    <option value="2">BBB</option>
    <option value="3">CCC</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PersonID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>